# How to extract layer rotation (transform) in jsx photoshop script?

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script, jsx

After I use `Free Transform` tool to rotate layer by 90 degrees...

How do I find this value using jsx script?

Answer (score 16):

Oh my good, it took me 4 hours to find this out :(

```
function angleFromMatrix(yy, xy)
{
    var toDegs = 180/Math.PI;
    return Math.atan2(yy, xy) * toDegs - 90;
}

function getActiveLayerRotation()
{
    var ref = new ActionReference();
    ref.putEnumerated( charIDToTypeID("Lyr "), charIDToTypeID("Ordn"), charIDToTypeID("Trgt") );
    var desc = executeActionGet(ref).getObjectValue(stringIDToTypeID('textKey'))
    if (desc.hasKey(stringIDToTypeID('transform')))
    {
        desc = desc.getObjectValue(stringIDToTypeID('transform'))
        var yy = desc.getDouble(stringIDToTypeID('yy'));
        var xy = desc.getDouble(stringIDToTypeID('xy'));
        return angleFromMatrix(yy, xy);
    }
    return 0;
}
```